# How to make line and circle with button and Text view in the same Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, line

How can I make a line with `Button` in the same `Activity`?
After I made a `Button` in `XML` file, I tried to make a line.

But when I tried to make line, I could not use

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I could use this:

```
    ViewMenu vm = new ViewMenu(this);
    vm.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    setContentView(vm);
```

How can I make line with `Button` in the same `Activity`?

Could anyone add an example code??

add code

```
activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Methode onCreate() in MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewMenu vm = new ViewMenu(this);
    vm.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    setContentView(vm);
}
```

ViewMenu class

```
public class ViewMenu extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public ViewMenu(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  }

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 1000, 1000, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(500, 1000, 700, 10, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Line with Button ?? Could you please post an image that shows how should the layout look like ?

Comment: i added source code. could you help me??

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom view to the layout's xml file

Answer (score 0):

You can use an custom view to draw the line such as LineView.

In your XML put the code like below to achieve the layout you want. So you can set the line whenever you want(At specific position like at above, below, left or right of any component).

```
<com.android.drawable.LineView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/secondButton"
    android:layout_below="@id/leftButton"
    android:layout_above="@id/rightButton"
    />
```